# Почему так ужасно оформлены непрочитанные уведомления?

Tags: дефект, дизайн

1. С отступами какая-то ерунда - верхнее лошадиное, по бокам вообще нет.
2. Действие и заголовок выделены одинаково.
3. Фон слишком тёмный.
4. Оно как будто висит в воздухе.
5. С многоточием тоже что-то странное.

[image: скриншот]

[image: скриншот]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: related? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330780/260198

Comment: @Suvitruf, неа, то уже исправили.

Comment: Инбоксы они такие: [раз](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305093/339911), [два](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290360/339911)